# How to combine currvita and ragged2e?

Tags: ragged2e, currvita

When I use ragged2e with currvita, then the currvita section headers loose their margin below, resulting in unacceptable ugly layout.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{currvita}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
\RaggedRight
\begin{cv}{CV}
\begin{cvlist}{List}
\item[Item]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.}
\end{cvlist}
\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

Google has shown me that the same problem apparently already existed more than ten years ago, see [currvita und ragged2e](https://groups.google.com/forum/?_escaped_fragment_=topic/de.comp.text.tex/ihJv-LqtAYE#!topic/de.comp.text.tex/ihJv-LqtAYE). There was no real solution (they suggested using an older version of ragged2e).

The problem can be kinda fixed when `\RaggedRight` is placed after each `\item`, like so:

```
\item[Item]\RaggedRight{Lorem ipsum ...}
```

I thought it would be very handy if `\item` could be redefined in such a way that the fix is applied automatically. I put the following in the preamble, but it would not have any effect:

```
\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand{\item}[1]{\olditem#1\RaggedRight}
```

What do I have to do in order to get `\RaggedRight` after each `\item`? Or is there a better way to combine ragged2e with currvita?

Comment: Apparently, the `currvita` package is from 1999, so a little bit aged. Perhaps, you should consider to use another one.